# Add UISlider to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to add a `UISlider` to a `UIView` to add to my `UIAlertController` for an easier but am unsure of the method.  In Objective C you would call `addSubview` but I am unsure of what it is in swift.

```
  //UIViewController.alertReminden(timeInterval)

            var refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Reminder", message: "Set a reminder for the bus in \(self.timeInterval) minutes.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                Alarm.createReminder("Catch the Bus",
                    timeInterval: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: Double(self.timeInterval * 60)))
            }))

            refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                println("Handle Cancel Logic here")
            }))

            var view = UIViewController();


            var myFrame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 250.0, 25.0)

            var slider = UISlider(frame: myFrame)

            slider.minimumValue = 1
            slider.maximumValue = 50
            slider.value = Float(timeInterval)

            view.addSubview(slider)

            refreshAlert.addChildViewController(view)



            self.viewForBaselineLayout()!.parentViewController?.presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In swift you can use addSubView too.

```
parentView.addSubView(childView)
```

In your case you would do

```
view.view.addSubView(slider)
```

To add to the `UIAlertController` you have to access its `view` property like so:

```
refreshAlert.view.addSubView(view.view)
```

Comment: This did work however the view still does not show up in the UIAlertController

Comment: Have you tried doing `refreshAlert.addSubView(view.view)` ?

Comment: UIAlertController does not have a addSubView Method only             refreshAlert.addChildViewController()  which takes a UIViewController not a UIView

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll look into the issue for you

Comment: @applejuiceteaching OK, it seems you have to do `refreshAlert.view.addSubView(view.view)`